# Let $A$ be a given matrix. Then there exists some $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax = 0$, $x \ge 0$ or there exists some $p$ such that $A^Tp > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

Exactly one of the alternatives must hold.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that there exists some $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax = 0$, $x \ge  0$.

By contradiction, let's suppose that $A^Tp \gt 0$ for some $p$.
Since $x \ge 0$ and $x \ne 0$, we have:

$(A^Tp)^Tx > 0 
\Rightarrow p^T(Ax) > 0
\Rightarrow p^T0 
\Rightarrow 0 > 0$

Which is a contradiction. Thus the second alternative doesn't hold.

Is that correct?

Now,  if we suppose that the first alternative doesn't hold, how could I prove
that the second alternative won't hold?

I think I should use something about  linear programming and duality but
I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $x\ge 0$ for a vector?

Comment: It means $x_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1, ..., n$.

Comment: you're misunderstanding what "or" means

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove is of the form A or B. You've shown that A implies (not B), which is interesting, but irrelevant to the question at hand

Comment: One correct way to prove the statement is to show that (not A) implies B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It suffices to show that either the transformation $T(p)=A^Tp$ is onto, or $A$ has a nontrivial nullspace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified form of Farkas's Lemma. The proves that I am aware of rely on the concept of separating hyperplanes. These concepts are commonly used in linear programming and convex optimization.